# Rendering navigation bar only after log in/sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Devise to handle user authentication and would like my navigation bar to render only if a user has signed up/ logged in. I do not want it showing on my landing page. I was able to get it to not render when on the log in page:

```
<%= render 'shared/navigation' unless current_page?(user_session_url) %>
```

but it would  not take multiple URL's.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
<%= render 'shared/navigation' if current_user %>
```

Devise gives you `current_user` helper which will return user object if the user is signed up or logged in and `false` if not.

Or you can also use `user_signed_in?` method which will return boolean value as `true` if the user is logged in or `false` if not:

```
<%= render 'shared/navigation' if user_signed_in? %>
```

Comment: There is also a `user_signed_in?` method which just returns a Boolean value and it can be nicer to read: `<%= render 'shared/navigation' if user_signed_in? %>`

Comment: Agree! Feel free to edit my answer, I'll accept it with pleasure.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I didn't think to use Devise's helper to render the nav bar- I seem to have focused on the page url and not on checking if there was a current user! Both current_user and user_signed_in? work out great! Thank you @VAD